# Python - Creating a league table, that displays the lines separately and a function to extract certain lines

Tags: python

I am trying to write three funcitons that, create a league table(I used 3 teams to make it easier to test but in practice there will be 16), calculate the points of those teams (3 points for a win, 1 point for a draw and 0 for a loss) and a function that, given the name of a team will return all its information. The saveInfo function works and the createLeague function works however it only returns the first line not the subsequent 2, also the getTeam function returns (none).

```
def saveInfo():
    myFile=open("league.txt","w")
    for i in range(3):
        team=input("Enter name of team: ")
        matchesPlayed=input("Enter number of matches played: ")
        matchesWon=int(input("Enter number of matches won: "))
        matchesDrawn=int(input("Enter number of matches drawn: "))
        matchesLost=int(input("Enter number of matches lost: "))
        return team,"",matchesPlayed,"",matchesWon,"",matchesDrawn,"",matchesLost
     myFile.close()

def createLeague():
    myFile=open("league.txt","r")
    points=0
    for info in myFile:
        for i in range(3):
            info=info.rstrip("/n")
            team_info=info.split()
            team_info[2]=int(team_info[2])
            team_info[3]=int(team_info[3])
            points=(team_info[2]*3)+(team_info[3]*1)
            team_info.append(points)
            return team_info   
     myFile.close()

def getTeam():
    name="Enter name of team"
    myFile=open("league.txt","r")
    team_info=""
    for line in myFile:
        info=info.rstrip("/n")
        team_info=info.split()
        if team_info[0]==name:
            print(team_info)
    myFile.close()

saveInfo()
team_info=createLeague
print(createLeague()) # only displays first line not the other 2
```

Comment: `return` ends the function. To return multiple things you must gather them into a list.

Answer (score 0):

That's accurate per your code.  **create_league** enters the loop, processes the first item, and then returns that team's info without going back to the top of the loop.  You *told* it to return as soon as it gets to that point.  You need to allow it to finish the loop, writing and collecting things in whatever form you're using.

Similarly, **getTeam** doesn't return anything: there's no **return** statement at all.  That's why the return value is **None**.

I can't show you how to fix this, since you haven't specified the functionality in your posting, but that's where you're going wrong.  It *looks* as if you may be confusing yourself between the information you write to a file, compared to what you return in communicating between the function and the calling routine.

Answer (score 0):

There are mistakes to your code

1. You put return on the loop, that's why it only loop once, then get out of the loop
2. You did not write anything to file

Probably you mean something like this

```
  def save_info():
        with open("league.txt","w") as myFile:
            for i in range(3):
                team=input("Enter name of team: ")
                matchesPlayed=input("Enter number of matches played: ")
                matchesWon=int(input("Enter number of matches won: "))
                matchesDrawn=int(input("Enter number of matches drawn: "))
                matchesLost=int(input("Enter number of matches lost: "))
                myFile.write("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}\n".format(team,matchesPlayed,matchesWon,matchesDrawn,matchesLost))


    def create_league():
        with open("league.txt","r") as myFile:
            contents = myFile.readlines()
            for content in contents:
                content.rstrip('\n')
                team_info=content.split(",")
                team_info[2]=int(team_info[2])
                team_info[3]=int(team_info[3])
                points=(team_info[2]*3)+(team_info[3]*1)
                print(points)

save_info()
create_league()
```

same applies to get_team method, and you should use snake case instead of camel case for python method